Information for a crystal or oscillator
I want information about this crystal.  I don't know how to read this crystal.


That is a crystal in industry standard HC49 package.
Based on the markings printed on it, it is a 8.000 MHz crystal manufactured by TXC Corporation.
All other parameters of the crystal can't be retrieved from the markings and are thus unknown.

we can say that it's not been soldered down, and that with only 4 significant digits in its frequency spec, it's probably a pretty unimpressive part, in an application where an error of 100 ppm probably doesn't hurt much.

@MarcusMüller The precision of a crystal is not defined by how many significant digits you can print on it. I've seen "25.000" printed on a crystal used for Ethernet and to be within specs, the crystal must be within a total of +/- 50 ppm, including initial tolerance, temperature stability, aging, and component and manufacturing tolerances for load capacitors and stray capacitance of PCB traces and IC pins.

You're obviously right, but it's my experience if all the device shows is "8.000" and not "8.0000" or "8.0000\n lot/proddate code" or similar, then it's typically a least-cost oscillator

Very likely a crystal to clock a MCU. Judging by the non-low-profile, through-hole HC49, I'd say it is probably clocking a fancy Motorola 6800 or other such bleeding edge technology :)
